# bindings set by general-define-key only work after entering insert-state

Tags: key-bindings, evil

```
;; emacs -Q (emacs version 29.1, emacs-mac)

(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents (package-refresh-contents))
(package-install-selected-packages)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t) 

(use-package evil :config (evil-mode 1))

(defun test () (interactive) (message "test"))
(define-minor-mode dummy-mode "" nil " Dummy" '())

(general-define-key
 :states 'normal
 :keymaps 'dummy-mode-map
 "C-j" #'test)
```

Here is what I did (make sure you never enter evil `insert-state` while doing this):

- eval the above code
- keeping `evil-mode` in `normal-state`, enter `dummy-mode`
- press `C-j` (it doesn't run test, because the binding is not setup)
- enter `insert-state`, and then return to `normal-state`
- press `C-j` (now it does run test)

Could this be a bug? I would like my bindings to work without needing to enter `insert-state`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, although unclear if it's in `general.el` or in `evil`. But unless you can prove that it's a bug in Evil, I think it will likely be closed because outwardly it looks like a bug in the other mode *(even if it's actually not — to prove you have to create a minimal testcase that uses evil-only functional and shows the bug)*. So I suggest you to start by reporting to `general.el` *(or create a min. testcase for Evil)*. Idk what else to say here… Unless on this post stumbles upon a `general.el`'s maintainer *(which is unlikely)*, I don't think there's anything else to answer here.